# WCF Periodical Function

Tags: wcf

I have a function in WCF service.
this function must be run at 00:30 am(everyday).
how implement it? (this service are always up)

tanx.
**Edit:**
if have functionality(in WCF) that can run function periodically also my problem be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you need to call an operation in a WCF service at a certain time in the day? You can simply create a client for the service in an .exe application and add a scheduled task which calls that client.

Comment: +1 exactly - there's nothing in WCF that would allow something like "scheduled calls" - use the existing Windows infrastructure for that

Comment: thanks for reply. I can't use Scheduled task because of user(that service install for him) can stop scheduling, therefore whole application is go wrong

Comment: WCF itself doesn't have any scheduler functionality. If the service is accessed from another machine, you can create a client on a machine which the user doesn't control to access the service. But the scheduling is something outside of the realm of WCF.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your service to run at a given time, then I think Windows Service would be a better option. You can also create a console app and create a scheduled task to run at a given time.